# CSS Transform not working in IE 8 and IE7 browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

i want to rotate a span text using css transform in IE7 and IE8 browser.

```
<SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 14px; -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);   FONT-FAMILY: Segoe UI; POSITION: absolute; ZOOM: 1; COLOR: #707070; LEFT: -64px;  TOP: 234px; VISIBILITY: visible">Sales Amount in millions(USD)
</SPAN>
```

above code will rotate the text in IE9+ and other browsers. but how can i rotate the  span text that will work in IE7 and IE8 browser.

[filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to support older version

how can i use filter to rotate span element ?

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 3):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

The rotation property of the BasicImage filter can accept one of four values: 0, 1, 2, or 3 which will rotate the element 0, 90, 180 or 270 degress respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Some of new attributes of css can implement with filter attribute for IE. For example If you want to have scale transform you use:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
-moz-transform: scale(1.05);
-o-transform: scale(1.05);
```

and etc extensions for non IE browsers.
But If you Want to use this for IE 8 or older. you should do this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.05,M12=0,M21=0,M22=1.05,SizingMethod='auto expand');
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use Matrix Filtering which is depracated from IE 9 and on.
Furthermore as they mention on this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014(v=vs.85).aspx

```
Resizes, rotates, or reverses the content of the object using matrix transformation.
```

And here is another link to make it easier for you:
http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html

Example of 90deg rotation:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.00000000, M12=-1.00000000, M21=1.00000000, M22=0.00000000,sizingMethod='auto expand')";
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.00000000, M12=-1.00000000, M21=1.00000000, M22=0.00000000,sizingMethod='auto expand');
-moz-transform:  matrix(0.00000000, 1.00000000, -1.00000000, 0.00000000, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform:  matrix(0.00000000, 1.00000000, -1.00000000, 0.00000000, 0, 0);
-o-transform:  matrix(0.00000000, 1.00000000, -1.00000000, 0.00000000, 0, 0);
```